# Typed / written + why / by + (a) + phone

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm translating the signature for the email App into English. I want it short but correct!

I have tried different searches in Google and Linguee. However, none of the following possibilities seem popular on Google (and I don't find them on Linguee). So maybe none of the following options is correct?

- Email typed with a phone. Apologies for the briefness.
- Email written by phone. Apologies for the briefness.
- (and other combinations using the same words).

How do you actually write that sentence normally in a short way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your word choice I would probably go with:

Written by phone, apologies for brevity.

Though in the US I typically see something like "Sent via phone - please excuse typos and informalities."

Comment: thanks man, I went for the first option, as right now I'm in Ireland! :)